# google-appengine appcfg.py downloading source files gives Couldn't create directory

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, appcfg

I uploaded code to app engine and now wish to download it.  In order to download it I'm using the cloudshell and entered the following command:

```
cloudshell: ~$ appcfg.py -A [proj-noah] -V [version] download_app /home/vicktree/Desktop/folder
```

When I run it, I'm get the following error

```
2020-01-09 8:12:27,793 ERROR appcfg.py:1655 Couldn't create directory "home/vicktree/Destktop/folder/" [Error 13] Permission denied: 'home/vicktree'
```

I am doing something wrong with the directory?

The download did work once but at that time the path used was 'home/vicktree/Desktop/' and didn't the slash (/) before the `home`.  But when I checked the Desktop directory, nothing was there. The operating system I'm using is Linux.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use this command have to run it without "[ ]". Just run

`appcfg.py -A proj-noah -V your_version_here download_app /home/vicktree/Desktop/folder`

Second make sure that you are logged in. Run the `gcloud init` command before running the `appcfg`

Comment: i originally run it in the cloud console shell.  Are you suggesting i to it in terminal? I did do 'gcloud init' but it still said appcfg.py.  Is there a folder i should be in? thanks

Comment: I didin't mean that you shouldn't run this in Cloudshell. I just tried myself and it worked fine. Can you please try again and provide us with a [HAR file](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting]? or a screenshot of the console were you run the command, the error and also the folder structure if is possible?

Comment: Just to be sure. Your user is 'vicktree'?

Comment: i got it working in local host going into the directory with the 'appcfg.py' file.  It is downloading it and the files are being added to the correct directory.  I tried to do the same with the cloudshell and its still saying permission denied

Comment: i added a screenshot of the cloudshell below

Comment: I'm glad to hear that is working in local. Seems like you don't have permissions to write on the 'vicktree' folder. Cna you please position yourself on he thome directory and run the command ls -la vicktree/ to see your permissions?